# "Hello, Old Soak," Came the Loud and Carefree Hail. "How Go Things?"

Tags: grammar, interrogatives

> "Hello, old soak," came the loud and carefree hail. "**How go things**?"
>
> — Isaac Asimov

May this seem, maybe, grammatically proper?

> How goes it?
>
> What say you?

And, may these seem, maybe, grammatically proper?

Answer (score 4):

The following two show normal subject/verb agreement:

> How go things?

Subject: things
Verb: go

Things go (how?).

> How goes it?

Subject: it
Verb: goes

It goes (how?).

The next one is grammatical but old fashioned; but it shows normal subject-verb agreement:

> What say you?

Subject: you
Verb: say

You say (what?).

In today's English you would usually say

> What do you say?

You do say (what?).

Might I comment on a sentence  in your answer that uses a highly unnatural style and choice of words? –one which you use over and over in your questions?

> May this seem, maybe, grammatically proper?

This sentence is entirely unnatural, and probably no native speaker would use this. Just use the verb *to be* and stop using the modal *may*, the verb *seem*, and the word *maybe* (although this last thing is the least unnatural).

Therefore just ask:

> **Is this grammatically correct?**

Comment: I would say "What say you?" is more "What do you have to say?", a minor point.

Comment: @Peter yeah, thanks. I hadn't thought about that. I think it can have that force, but not always.

Comment: @AlaneCarmack Let's see whether I got it. "How go things?" is old fashion and in modern English, which I learned, "How do things go?" is correct and the former not, isn't it? Or is it still possible and common to use it?

Comment: So, all three, *How go things?*, *How goes it?*, and *What say you?* may work, and seem grammatically proper? So, I guess, may you use all, and, or, any, of the three?

Comment: @saySay Do you know the difference between *to be* and *to seem*? Why do you constantly use the modal *may*?

Comment: @sina *How do things go?* is not idiomatic as a greeting.  You can say *How are things going?* or even *How are things?* The expression *How go things?* may be old fashioned  but native speakers still use it sometimes. *How goes it?* is probably more common.

Comment: Also, "How's it going?", "How are things?" get used a lot. "Hey, what do you say?" is an much older informal way of saying "Hi!", and then there's always "[How you doin' ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjQ1xD6UL-4)